# Equivalent of "in" for If Then in VB Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to using VBA macros in Excel. I want to check for a string value in a set of other string values. For example: is value of `cc` variable in `("Q6", "_Q6", "1_Q", "2_Q", "3_Q", "4_Q")` where `cc` could be `Q6`.

My pseudo-code is:

```
If cc in ("Q6", "_Q6", "1_Q", "2_Q", "3_Q", "4_Q") Then
```

I don't know what operator should be in place of `in`. So, what should be instead of `in` because currently it giving me syntax error. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Select Case` statement can do this quite nicely (and efficiently). 
See http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-select-case-statement/

```
Select Case cc
    Case "Q6", "_Q6", "1_Q", "2_Q", "3_Q", "4_Q"
        ' If ... Then
        ' Stuff you want to do if any of the above
    Case Else
        ' Else
        ' Whatever you if none of the above
End Select
```

Comment: Thats what I have done. It was simple and efficient :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Filter` function which will return a string array if the match is found. For your example:

`UBound(Filter(Array("Q6", "_Q6", "1_Q", "2_Q", "3_Q", "4_Q"), "Q6", True, vbBinaryCompare))`

That returns `1` but note that if the 3rd argument is `False` then it will return the items of the array that don't match the input, which would be `5`.

A more complete example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim varData As Variant
    Dim strCC As String
    Dim varFilter As Variant
    Dim intCounter As Integer

    varData = Array("Q6", "_Q6", "1_Q", "2_Q", "3_Q", "4_Q")
    strCC = "foo"
    varFilter = Filter(varData, strCC, True, vbBinaryCompare)
    For intCounter = LBound(varFilter) To UBound(varFilter)
        Debug.Print varFilter(intCounter)
    Next intCounter

End Sub
```